# Instantiating a non-primitive type with CodeDom

Tags: .net, instantiation, codedom

I'm trying to use CodeDom to instantiate an instance of System.Drawing.Font but I can't work out how to create a new type, specifically for the FontFamily and FontStyle parameters.

If I execute the following code:

```
CodeExpression[] parms = new CodeExpression[3];

parms[0] = new CodePrimitiveExpression(((System.Drawing.Font)value).FontFamily.Name);
parms[1] = new CodePrimitiveExpression(((System.Drawing.Font)value).Size);
parms[2] = new CodePrimitiveExpression(((System.Drawing.Font)value).Style);

codeObjectCreateExpression = new CodeObjectCreateExpression("System.Drawing.Font", parms);
```

I get an error

> Invalid Primitive Type: System.Drawing.FontStyle. Consider using CodeObjectCreateExpression.

From reading around, I know I have to use `CodeObjectCreateExpression` to create an instance of a type, but I'm unsure how to assign [anything apart from primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeprimitiveexpression.aspx)  to it.

Comment: I dont understand what you are having a problem with. The `CodeObjectCreateExpression(Type, CodeExpression[])` overload looks quite simple and self-explanatory.

Comment: @leppie I've included some code, I hope this makes more sense, I've a feeling I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're actually using? Because you're not passing `FontFamily` to `CodePrimitiveExpression` constructor in your code.

Comment: @svick - I've updated the code to where I'm up to but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use any object, then you can't do that (at least not without using hacks like serialization or accessing private fields using reflection). That's because CodeDOM tree has to be translated to C# (or another .Net language). And CodeDOM has no idea how to write code that would construct that object (Should it call a constructor? Which one? Or a factory method? Or something else?).

But if it's just `enum`s (like `FontStyle`) that you have problems with, you can get its value as if you were accessing a `static` field on the `enum` type:

```
new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("System.Drawing.FontStyle"),
    ((System.Drawing.Font)value).Style.ToString())
```

Comment: Just about to write similar (although my rusty old code uses a property reference rather than a field reference). It falls down if more than one flag is set in the enum value (what with `FontStyle` being a flags enum...)

Comment: @Svick - Many thanks for taking the time to answer, I understand where I was going wrong with it and my perceptions of how CodeDom works.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Interesting you should mention that, an example I found has a work around. Look for the method EvalEnums() at this url: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Content/ViewAssociatedFile.aspx?rzp=%2FKB%2FXML%2Fxmlcompiler%2FxmlCompiler.zip&zep=Clifton.Tools.Xml%2FCodeGen.cs&obid=11629&obtid=2&ovid=1

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yeah, I don't think about flags. You're right, my sample code wouldn't work correctly with them.